# 2 in 1: modify php value in runtime, inside echo

Tags: javascript, php, function, echo

I`ll try to explain the best that I can.
I don't know anything about PHP, and very little about js, so, forgive me if this question is stupid.

I'm trying to load a PHP function inside an echo.

*this is the function i want to call*

```
function SuccessDialog(){

    if(isset($_POST['mailsent']))
      {
          $to      = 'mymail@hotmail.it';
          $subject = 'test2';
          $message = 'hello';
          $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
              'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
              'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

          mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


      }

    }
```

I need to call this when an upload is successfull and an "echo" opens a dialog, in which there should be a "send email button" (at the moment I don't care about the mail is working or not, since it is).

*The script for said button is this*

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Send email" />
<input type="hidden" name="mailsent" value="1" />
</form>
```

(actually I can't understand why it should be inside a form, but it's working)

And so, the first part of the question. Since this code is working if used with a button outside the echo, how can I manage to make it work with this particular button?

And here for the second question.

Since the email address should be an input from the user, I should be able to modify the "$to" in runtime, still being inside the echo. Can I do that, or since php is server side I'm stuck or I got it wrong from the beginning?

Thanks

Comment: `I got it wrong from the beginning` - That's the answer.

Comment: @Kinshuk Lahiri thanks. Irony is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: "load a PHP function" ? This is simply done by letting the PHP interpreter reading the function's definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I got it right, you have to add

`<input type="text" name="to">`

to the form, and you wold be able to get the value in `$_POST['to']` in php. Remember to sanitize user input!

**edit**

1. To make user unable to submit the form without adding an email address add `required` attribute to the field.
2. You can use `type="email"` to make browser (a new one) validate the input.

Comment: Possibly we can use `<input type="email" name="to" required>`

Comment: @VigneshChinnaiyan yes, I think you are right, thanks. Added to the answer